# drag items in resizable canvas

Tags: wpf, resize, controls, traversal

I'm designing a spline editor which is composed of two parts (usercontrols)
The left control is the **DesignerControl** and the right one is the **InfoControl**. They share the same DataContext: **DesignerVM** with an

```
ObservableCollection<SplineVM> SplineVMList;
```

**DesignerControl** is an **ItemsControl** templated as a **Canvas** ("mycanvas") with ItemsSource bound to **SplineVMList** and ItemTemplate set as **SplineControl**.
**InfoControl** is a ListBox displaying the **SplineVMs** and a **Grid** displaying the SplineVMs' Properties.

In **SplineControl** I have a Canvas containing 4 draggable Points (Rectangle) and 2 Lines that will be bound to these Points. Everything works, I can drag my points, my lines move.

```
<UserControl>
    <Canvas Width="300" Height="300" x:Name="mycanvas" Background="Transparent">
        <Path x:Name="curve" Stroke="#F02828" StrokeThickness="3">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathGeometry.Figures>
                        <PathFigureCollection>
                            <PathFigure>
                                <PathFigure.Segments>
                                    <PathSegmentCollection x:Name="pathsegment"/>
                                </PathFigure.Segments>
                            </PathFigure>
                        </PathFigureCollection>
                    </PathGeometry.Figures>
                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
        <Rectangle x:Name="curvePoint1" Width="10" Height="10" Canvas.Bottom="0" Canvas.Left="0" />
        <Rectangle x:Name="curvePoint2" Width="10" Height="10" RadiusX="4" RadiusY="4" Canvas.Bottom="0" Canvas.Left="{Binding ElementName=mycanvas, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource mathconverter}, ConverterParameter=(@VALUE/4)}"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="curvePoint3" Width="10" Height="10" RadiusX="4" RadiusY="4" Canvas.Bottom="0" Canvas.Left="{Binding ElementName=mycanvas, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource mathconverter}, ConverterParameter=(@VALUE/2)}"/>
        <Rectangle x:Name="curvepoint4" Width="10" Height="10" Canvas.Bottom="0" Canvas.Left="{Binding ElementName=mycanvas, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource mathconverter}, ConverterParameter=(@VALUE)}"/>
        <Line x:Name="line1" Stroke="#dfdfdf" StrokeThickness="1"/>
        <Line x:Name="line2" Stroke="#dfdfdf" StrokeThickness="1"/>
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

**My first problem** is that I have to use a container (here a Canvas) to hold the path, rectangles and lines.

When i add a **SplineControl** in mycanvas, it's well placed and i can instantly drag my points but when i add another UserControl, it's placed above the previous one and i can't select the first Usercontrol's points.

I don't want to use IsHitTestVisible since I want to select points from the first userControl through the second.

**My Second problem:**
Since I use a Canvas to hold my things in the SplineControl, i can drag points outside of the canvas and still interact with it, and at first sight it was great.

But thinking it again, i'd like to resize my Canvas when i move a point to always have my point in the canvas. but also have my other points positions updated respecting the ratio of mycanvas.

Do you know any control that have this behavior and can replace my Canvas?
Should i use CustomControl instead of UserControl?

May I have to think again my project's conception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Fact I've found a way to get around my first problem of item selection through other items.

`Canvas` that were under the selected one were unclickable because the `Color` of every `Canvas` was set to `Transparent`. So I could see them but not interact with them.

Since I've set the `Background` property to `Null` (or haven't set it explicitly), I can click through and select the items under the top one.

It's a strange behavior of WPF...
Does someone have an explanation?

It will solve my 2nd problem too, 'cause I'll set my `UserControl` with the size I want and still select other `UserControls` in my View.

It's a dirty trick but I'll avoid the `CustomPanel` thing then.

thx anyway akjoshi and Danny Varod for your concern  ^^
your answers were still useful since I'll use them in the other project I'm working on.
it's just that time is short on this one.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your application details using `Canvas` makes sense to me. I have worked on a similar application and created a `DesignerCanvas` allowing items movement, resizing etc. and worked well.

**First problem:** I also faced similar problem and decided to add a delta to the position of my control's; so say location of first control is 0,0 then next control will be placed at 10,10; and next at 20,20; this way all the controls have visible area and are slectable(as soon as it's selected it comes to top).

**Second problem**: It's not a big problem to increase the width and height of Canvas when a control is dragged and making sure that control is not allowed to place outside Canvas. Will try to see if I can find the code related to that.

Look at this article series having similar implementation -

WPF Diagram Designer - [Part 4](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24681/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-4), [Part 3](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23871/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-3), [Part 2](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23265/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-2), [Part 1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22952/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-1)